# accessing entity method inside other entity getting object reference error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity

i have entity classes and methods inside that like as below

```
public class OpaqueConstruction :AEIMasterBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public List<OpaqueMaterial> Layers { get; set; }

    public Construction AddToOsm(Model model)
    {
        if (model is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
        }

        // code 
        construction.setLayers(materials);
        return construction;
    }
    public OpaqueConstruction() { }
}

public class ConstructionSet : AEIMaster
{
    [ForeignKey("ExteriorWall"), GraphQLIgnore]
    public Guid? ExteriorWallId { get; set; }
    public virtual OpaqueConstruction ExteriorWall { get; set; }

    public void AddToOsm(Model model)
    {
        if (model is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
        }

        using var constructionSet = new DefaultConstructionSet(model);
        using var exteriorSurfaceConstructions = new DefaultSurfaceConstructions(model);

        using var exteriorWall = this.ExteriorWall.AddToOsm(model); // getting error at here object reference set exception
        exteriorSurfaceConstructions.setWallConstruction(exteriorWall);

    }
    public ConstructionSet () { }
}
```

I am trying to  access methods that has written in one entity from other entity  like as here `this.ExteriorWall.AddToOsm(model)` through navigation properties and getting object reference error and could not be able to figure it out and those classes are actual entities and i am using EF core with .net core

Could any one please let me know where i am doing wrong with the above code, many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you query for `ConstructionSet`, include `ExteriorWall` with it like -

```cs
var constructionSet = context.ConstructionSets.Include(p=> p.ExteriorWall).FirstOrDefault();
```

And, do a null check (the ? operator below) when you call the method on `ExteriorWall`, like -

```cs
var exteriorWall = this.ExteriorWall?.AddToOsm(model);
```

in case there is no related `OpaqueConstruction` data found for your `ConstructionSet`.